# CQRS and Event Sourcing Query Historical Data

Tags: domain-driven-design, cqrs, event-sourcing

When using CQRS and Event Sourcing how does one query historical data. As an example if I am building a timesheet system that has a report for revenue I need to query against hours, pay rate, and bill rate for each employee. There is a EMPLOYEE_PAY_RATE table that has EmployeeID, PayRate, and EffectiveDate, as well as a BILL_RATE table which has ClientID, EmployeeID, Rate, and EffectiveDate. The effective date in those tables is basically keeping the running history so we can report accurately.

If we were to take a DDD, CQRS, and Event Sourcing Route how would we generate such a report? It's not like we can query the event store in the same way. I've looked at frameworks like Axon but not sure if it would allow us to do what we need to do from a reporting perspective.

Answer (score 2):

> When using CQRS and Event Sourcing how does one query historical data.

Pretty much the same way you query live data: you build the views that you want from the event history, and then query the views for the data that you want.

To borrow your example - your view might be supported by an EMPLOYEE_PAY_RATE table and a BILL_RATE table.  Replay your events, as something interesting happens update the appropriate table.  TaDa.

An important idea that may not be obvious - for something low latency like a history report, you'll probably want the historical aggregator to be pulling the events from the event store, rather than having a bus push events to the aggregator.  The pull approach makes it a lot easier to keep track of where you are, so that you don't need to repeat a lot of work, worry about whether you've received all of the events you should, ordering, and so on.

Answer (score 1):

You report is just another read-model/projection of the events, for example a SQL table that is populated by listening to the relevant events.

If the table is big, i.e. a lot of employees, in order to be fast, you should avoid using `joins`, by keeping the data denormalized; so, for every employee and day (or whatever granularity you want) you would have a row in a table containing the Employee ID **and name**, the start date and the end date of the day and other columns containing relevant data, i.e. the pay rate. You put heer the employee name also in order to avoid the `joins` and you keep it up-to-date by listening to the relevant employee events (like `EmployeeChangedName`).

Comment: I would need projections of several events though. Over a year period the BillRate for an employee may change 2-3 times, and they employee themselves might have 1-2 pay raises. The report calculations would also have to take hours and dates from Timesheet entity and intersect all that data to calculate properly. Is that still feasible? In the past I've done it with SQL but it was a complex but fast query, doing all that in memory seems problematic from a resource perspective.

Comment: @jkratz55 why more than one projection? One seems to be enough.

Comment: I'm probably just not understand the concepts having never done CQRS and Event Sourcing but in our present old system, I am joining EMPLOYEE, TIMESHEET, EMPLOYEE_PAY_RATE, CLIENT_BILL_RATE, and PROJECT_ASSIGNMENT tables together to generate the report. Timesheet has the hours for a particular employee for given day and project. Bill Rate and Pay Rate tables have effective start date columns so it has all historical data. I guess I can't visualize how that would be accomplished using an event store and replaying events.

Comment: @jkratz55 in CQRS you *can* have only one super-fast table for the report with denormalized data so you don't have to use any joins